# Dedicated Minecraft server that's Xbox accessible

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've got a Minecraft server hosted via docker that my friends are enjoying but some can't because they only have xboxes that can reliably play Minecraft.  Is there a way to host a Minecraft server on a Linux server that XBox users can use?

I've seen answers that say no but they're all fairly old - as the game is.

Comment: Are you asking if a server can have both Linux and Xbox players? I can't tell, but if/when I get clarification I'll change this to an answer if it was what you're asking. If so then the answer is no, Linux users and Xbox users cannot play together. Linux uses the Java edition but Xbox uses the Bedrock edition, they are 2 separate games (more or less) and cannot work together.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe can a Bedrock server be hosted on a Linux OS?

Comment: @DJSpicyDelux. Thank you for clarifying the difference between the java and bedrock servers.  I was under the false impression that the server was the same and Xbox clients were garden walled somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, considering Vanilla versions<sup>¹</sup>, it is not possible.

There are [different Minecraft versions](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1274139-different-minecraft-editions) as people pointed out on the comments. The only available version for Xbox (Either 360 or one) is the Bedrock edition, while for Linux, the only available version is the Java one.

<sub>¹I cannot guarantee that there isn't a modification that either allows the Bedrock edition to be played on Linux or emulates the Java on Xbox. I at least know none nor saw any mention of it.</sub>

Comment: fwiw I would be amazed if there wasn't a hack for running either client in foreign environments.  Bedrock in wine, arbitrary jvm program on a windows machine (Xbox).